# Unable to import .less file from node_modules using module-name in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, less, frontend, angular6

I am trying to import styles from a custom library packaged as a node-module.
Suppose the package name is @custom. I intend to import a less file from inside  @custom package in the following way:

```
@import '@custom/styles/common.less'
```

This statment searches for `'@custom/styles/common.less'` in the same folder where I have added this import statement.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.less
Module build failed:

@import "@custom/styles/common";
^
Can't resolve './@custom/styles/common.less' in '<path>\src\app'
      in <path>\src\app\app.component.less (line 1, column 0)
```

Is there a way to declare the `relative-path` or the `module-name` so that it searches in node-modules folder? Or am I missing something very basic?

Comment: To use module alias, you need to configure them in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Post your tsconfig as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it, if you need to just compile them along with your project, then include it in your angular-cli like below:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/custom/styles/common.less"
```

if you want to use the less files in your project and use their variables then you have to include it in your angular-cli file as below:

```
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "../node_modules/custom/styles"
    ]
  },
```

and in your component style files you can include the less files like `@import '../styles/<your parent less file>';`